# Type declarations use wrong path when exported from node module

Tags: typescript, npm, emotion

### Background

I am creating an NPM package in TypeScript that outputs declarations. The project consumes type declarations from other packages, such as [react-emotion](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-emotion).

### Problem

When the declarations of my package are compiled by TypeScript, it generates the incorrect URL for the type declarations of the `create-emotion-styled` package. **Example**:

**`IconStyled.ts`:**

```js
import styled from 'react-emotion';
import { BaseIcons } from './BaseIcons';
import { colors, props } from 'flooz-common';

const { INK } = colors;

interface IconsProps {
    fill?: string;
    stroke?: string;
    strokeWidth?: string | number;
}

export const Icon = styled(BaseIcons)`
    fill: ${(props: IconsProps) => (props.fill ? props.fill : 'transparent')};
    stroke: ${(props: IconsProps) => (props.fill ? `transparent` : `${INK}`)};
    stroke: ${(props: IconsProps) => props.stroke && props.stroke};
    stroke-width: ${(props: IconsProps) =>
        props.strokeWidth ? `${props.strokeWidth}px` : '4px'}};
    ${props.padding};
`;
```

**`IconStyled.d.ts`:**

```js
interface IconsProps {
    fill?: string;
    stroke?: string;
    strokeWidth?: string | number;
}
export declare const Icon: import("../../../../../../../../../../Users/flim/flam/packages/flooz-icon/node_modules/create-emotion-styled/types/react").StyledStatelessComponent<IconsProps, {
    className?: string;
    name: string;
    size: number;
}, any>;
export {};
//# sourceMappingURL=IconStyled.d.ts.map
```

The path `"../../../../../../../../../../Users/flim/flam/packages/flooz-icon/node_modules/create-emotion-styled/types/react"` for the type declarations from `create-emotion-styled` is clearly **incorrect**.  I would like to fix this. I am guessing I might have a configuration error.

This is my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
        "declaration": true,
        "declarationMap": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "module": "es2015",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "outDir": "../lib/esm"
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "removeComments": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "es5",
        "pretty": true,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": [
          "dom",
          "dom.iterable",
          "es5",
          "es2015.collection",
          "es2015.iterable"
        ],
        "typeRoots": ["../node_modules/@types"],
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "noImplicitAny": true
    }
}
```

Any help / pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is a side effect of allowing to "transparently" expose non-imported types in exported declarations, see [relaxing declaration emit visibility in 2.9](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What%27s-new-in-TypeScript#relaxing-declaration-emit-visiblity-rules). The workaround is to add explicit `import {StyledStatelessComponent} from "whichever-module-it's-defined-in"`; I'd also suggest filing a bug in TypeScript repo.

Comment: @artem that was indeed the solution